# Error Result Values (Special Unreadable Charsaters) while using UnHex in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, hex, sql-function

I have a database with 1 table containing a Column "User_Data" in hex format. I want to extract these values Unhexed i.e printable values.

So I use the command:

```
Select UNHEX(User_Data) From DatabaseName.TableName
```

In the result most values appear in error format like some special characters (pasted below) & not printable values. Error Result:

One example Values in Hex Column:

```
596f757220496e7465726e6574206163636f756e7420776974682044484c2042524f414442414e44204e4554205b505d204c494d4954454420686176696e6720757365726e616d652020414a57414454524156454c2077696c6c20657870697265206f6e20323031362d31302d30332032303a30303a313620506c656173652
```

Error Result Achieved via above UnHex command:

```
��W"��FW&�WB66�V�Bv�F�D��%$�D$�B�UB��ĔԕDTB�f��rW6W&��R�tEE$dT�v���W��&R��#b��2#��b�V6R
```

Actual Result should have been something like:

```
Your Internet account with DHL BROADBAND NET [P] LIMITED having username AJWDTRAVEL will expire on 2016-10-03 20:00:16
```

Comment: Looking at a hex ASCII table, 59 is capital Y, 6f is lower case o, 57 is W and 22 is a non-printable character called "Synchronous Idle" or SYN. How did the text got into hex format?

Comment: Frankly i have been allotted this job.no idea o the same.

Comment: What `collation` is used on the database? Is it `utf8`? Where do you see this error - on the browser or console? Which engine is being using to read the data? Please ensure that encoding used is `utf8` across the database, tables, browser and query engines.

Comment: Yes it is utf8 and using navcat premium